# Moving median in MATLAB prior to R2016a

Tags: matlab, median

In MATLAB R2016a the function [`movmedian`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmedian.html) was introduced but I have an older version.

Does anyone know how to do something similar to what this function does without using loops? I need to call this function many times and speed is important.

Essentially, I have a 1000×1 vector `X` and I want another vector where each element equals
`Y(i)= median(X((i-50):(i+50)))`. If I use a loop, I can do this:

```
X=rand(1000,1);
Y=zeros(1000,1);

    for i=1:1000
        if i>=51
            start=i-50;
        else
            start=1;
        end
        if i<=950
            end1=i+50;
        else
            end1=1000;
        end
        Y(i)= median(X(start:end1));
    end
```

But I'm going to call this loop between 1,000 and 100,000 times with X changing content (but not size) on each iteration, and I'd like to see if there is something faster I can do.

I tried medfilt1, and it works pretty well except that I need the truncated series and when I use the command: medfilt1(X,101, 'truncate') I get the error 'Input arguments must be 'double'. Even though X is class double! I even run the exact example in [Matlab webpage for this command](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/medfilt1.html) and got the same error. Any idea what is going on with that? I tried this and got the same error: medfilt1(double(X),101, 'truncate')

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have testing to back up your assertion that loops are the limiting factor in your algorithm?

Comment: I might be missing something, but isn't `median(X(i-50):X(i+50))` the same as `median(X(i-1):X(i+1)`?

Comment: If you have the image processing toolbox, you can use `blockproc` with `@median`, or `im2col` and compute the median of each column

Comment: Excaza: Loops are typically slower than other functions, so I'm just asking if there is any that does what I want.

Comment: Griffin: Sorry, there was a misspelling I meant this: Y(i)= median(X((i-50):(i+50))) In other words, it is the median of 100 elements but the elements of X to compute the median change for each element of Y.

Comment: Loops being slower than other functions is heavily dependent on MATLAB version and how the function is written. I suggest you create something that functions and worry about optimization later.

Comment: Excaza - I already created a loop that works. At this point I was already working on the optimization.

Comment: Great, so back to my original question, do you have testing to back up your assertion that loops are the limiting factor in your algorithm? What is your current algorithm? [Where are the "slowdowns"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html)?

Comment: @Floren How many vectors like this you have (one, tens, thousands)? Are they all the same length, or having a variable length? What is larger, the vectors length or their number?

Comment: If you have the Signal Processing toolbox, you can use [medfilt1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/medfilt1.html). Otherwise, if you have the Image Processing toolbox, you can use [medfilt2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/medfilt2.html) and select a neighborhood height of 1. A third approach is to use `gallery('circul',X)`, select the appropriate columns, and take the medians of the rows. A more interesting approach would be to implement a specialized moving-window insertion sort.

Comment: Excaza - I put the loop example in my post. I don't have back up for my assertion because I don't have anything to compare the loop to, thus my question.

Comment: @EHB I'll be applying this to 7 vectors about 1000 elements each. Then I'll call this function between 1,000 and 100,000 times. Anything that speeds up the calculation will matter at the end.

Comment: @beaker. Thanks for the suggestions. medfilt1 is giving me an unexpected problem (see new edit to my post). gallery is a possibility but it may actually work slower than the loop... which defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Floren Yeah, `gallery` is going to be a nightmare for time **and** space complexity. ;) I'll have a look at your edit.

Comment: Does it work without the `'truncate'`?

Comment: It does, but then only 900 elements are usable, I need to get the other 100 from medians of the data available, just like what the code i wrote does, If I could use the 'truncate' option, it should do just that.

Comment: @Floren Understood, just trying to establish where the error is. The only thing I can think of is that perhaps your text editor is introducing smart quotes so the `'truncate'` is not seen as a string.

Comment: @Beaker - Good point, but I actually copied and paste the command from the Matlab website and now again from your own comment. There is something funky going on :( I think I will post a separate question on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can instead use [`medfilt1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/medfilt1.html)...

for example, say I have a single vector X, then:

```
  Xm=medfilt1(X,101);
```

no need for a for loop here... in my old laptop this takes for a 1000 length vector about 6e-4 seconds using timeit:

```
f=@() medfilt1(X,101);
timeit(f)
```

this means that 1e5 times that will take ~60 seconds.

Comment: Thanks Bla, I appreciate it. I added an edit about a problem I have with medfilt1.

Comment: can you give add please a minimal code that demonstrates your issue (how big X is etc)

Comment: The code I put in my post shows a very close example. The vector X has about 1000 elements and I will call this function between 1,000 and 100,000 times.

Comment: for 100000 different X vectors?

Comment: Yes, the X vector will change on each iteration but remain the same size.

Comment: i also dont understand why you need to truncate? just ignore the edges if you want... like  `Xm(50:end-50)` in my answer

Comment: I cannot just ignore it. If I ignore it I get a final vector that has 900 elements, I need it to have the same number of elements and obtain those elements from medians of the data available. Does it work for you if you do  Xm=medfilt1(X,101, 'truncate');? It does not for me...

Comment: `Xm=medfilt1(X,101, 'truncate');` works for me as intended. (I have Matlab 2015b) what you can do instead is `Xm=[X(1:50) Xm(51:end-50) X(end-49:end)];` if Xm is a row vector, otherwise use `;` in the `[..]`

Comment: Thanks Bla. I have Matlab 2015a and there is something funky going on with the truncate option :(  Unfortunately I cannot use your suggestions since the first and last 50 elements have to come from medians of the available data. Essentially the solution has to reproduce what I put in the loop. I think I'm going to put a different posting about this problem I have with 'truncate'...

Comment: just check you dont have an older medfilt1 copied somewhere in the path... or reset the path of the toolboxes using `!matlab &
exit`